# Duplicate Jenkins groovy yaml reading & writing on my workstation

Tags: maven, jenkins, groovy

I want to use `readYaml` and `writeYaml` locally on my workstation.

They're available on Jenkins via the Jenkinsfile and in the groovy scripts run during Jenkins builds, but locally I want to launch my groovy script via a maven plugin (I'm using polyglot maven for the yaml pom):

```
build:
    plugins:
      - artifactId: gmavenplus-plugin
        groupId: org.codehaus.gmavenplus
        version: 1.6.1
        executions:
          - goals: [ execute ]
        configuration:
            scripts: ["file:///${project.basedir}/src/main/groovy/local.groovy"]
        dependencies:
          - artifactId: groovy-all
            groupId: org.codehaus.groovy
            version: 2.5.1
            type: pom
```

and maven objects:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.gmavenplus:gmavenplus-plugin:1.6.1:execute 
     (default-cli) on project adam-test: 
     Error occurred while calling a method on a Groovy class from classpath.
     InvocationTargetException: No signature of method: Script1.readYaml() is
     applicable for argument types: (LinkedHashMap) values:
     [[file:kube/application.yml]] -> [Help 1]
```

I guess there's some import out there that I need, but googling isn't helping.

Has this been spun off from Jenkins into an independent library?

Alternatively, could I achieve the same thing with some other build plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply import `readYaml()` or `writeYaml()`, because they are not methods or functions, but Jenkins Pipeline workflow steps. For instance, when you execute `readYaml()` pipeline step, the following [`ReadYamlStep`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/conf/ReadYamlStep.java) class object gets involved in execution through Jenkins workflow Groovy CPS.

You can try adding `pipeline-utility-steps` plugin as a dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jenkins-ci.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>pipeline-utility-steps</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and then try make this `ReadYamlStep` class running, but this is really a horrible example of doing stuff. Just take a look - this dependency [has 8 compile dependencies](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jenkins-ci.plugins/pipeline-utility-steps/2.1.0) that will be added to your classpath.

Another thing - if you expect to execute your Groovy script outside Jenkins Pipeline environment then you will have to prepare a full Groovy CPS Workflow environment, which actually means simulating what Jenkins Workflow CPS plugin does. You can check [`ReadYamlStepTest`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/master/src/test/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/conf/ReadYamlStepTest.java) to see how Workflow CPS gets prepared for unit test environment to run pipeline script with support for `readYaml()` step definition.

---

### Using SnakeYAML

Jenkins Utility Steps uses [SnakeYAML](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.yaml/snakeyaml/1.21) for dealing with YAML files. Consider using this library outside Jenkins Pipeline environment - this library has no compile dependencies and you can get inspiration how to use it from `ReadYamlStep`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

---

### Conclusion

Jenkins pipeline scripts are not vanilla Groovy scripts and you can't execute them as a regular Groovy scripts outside Jenkins Workflow CPS environment.

Comment: Then it looks like I'll have to write the same functionality in pure snakeyaml just to execute the same functionality on my workstation - in which case I might go back a step or two and see if I can reorganise the yaml files so that I don't need to do this at all. Thank you for the info.